# Can I get the client IP address in express js api?

Tags: node.js, express, ip

I'm trying to make a chat app  using node.js as backend, where every client has a specific IP so I need to get the IP of the client using my api.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question by adding some code in order to understand it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a middleware [express-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ip)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressIp = require('express-ip');
app.use(expressIp().getIpInfoMiddleware);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.ipInfo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the variable from req object `req.connection.remoteAddress`

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
});
```